# Cannot Auto-Login to Facebook after Login to Gmail

Tags: facebook, google-account

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one log into Facebook using Linked Accounts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18711/how-does-one-log-into-facebook-using-linked-accounts)

I set my facebook link account to be my google account, and thus I expect that [I will be auto-login to facebook after I login to gmail](http://www.labnol.org/internet/facebook-autologin/8916/).

But this is not happening!! Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: i have same problem... my linked account stop working... i tried redoing the link with gmail, but an error appears and i cant go on with the procedure...
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know that Google and Facebook are having a bit of a barney about data usage at the moment. I don't know how long it's been going on for though. That might have something to do with it.

http://techcrunch.com/2010/11/10/google-gets-feisty-kicks-data-portability-fight-with-facebook-up-a-notch/

Answer (score 0):

Same problem was for me... I did same procedure today again. I went to account settings, linked accounts. Removed my gmail from there. And added Google again. Now it works. When I go to facebook, it waits few seconds and logins automatically...
But on my linked account settings there was my gmail e-mail address, but now there is a word "Google" instead... So that's the difference, try redoing the process again. But be logged in to Google all the time when you do the process. I didn't have to enter Google password even, when doing this. Only facebook password.