# How does one log into Facebook using Linked Accounts?

Tags: login, facebook, openid

I have linked my Yahoo and Google accounts with Facebook via the Account Settings. Both of them now appear in the Linked Accounts list. Displayed immediately above them is the following:

> If you are logged into one of the accounts below you will automatically be logged into Facebook.

Yet when I navigate to http://www.facebook.com/, I am still prompted to enter my Facebook username and password, whether I am logged into Yahoo, Google, or both.

What gives?

**Update:** Added bounty. I followed the steps exactly but Facebook still fails to log in. Tried Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.

The browser displays "Connecting to accounts.google.com" briefly, then "Connecting to www.facebook.com", then goes back to idle, and doesn't log in.

Comment: ? But you said you got through before :S This seems localized to me.

Comment: It seems something broke between Facebook and Google OpenID. Requests are being cancelled. I cannot look into this more now but it's not something that can be fixed on the user end. Consider reporting it to Facebook via their feedback forms.

Answer (score 4):

Did you wait for it to recognize the authentication? There should be something similar at the bottom of the browser that says

> Waiting for google.com ...

Then

> Waiting for accounts.google.com ...

I have did the following,

1. Added the linked account.
2. Logged out of Facebook.
3. Logged out of Google.
4. Logged in to Google.
5. Pointed my browser to facebook.com and waited a few seconds.

It automatically reached my homepage after that.
I have tried this a few times with even just logging out of Facebook, closing the window and returning to a new window with facebook.com open.

Comment: did not work for me. :(